# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/glog.framework/glog and app not opening

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have follow problem, somebody to help me. When I run by Xcode 12.4 show me follow error and app not open:

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/glog.framework/glog Referenced from: /Users/hugofv/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/....../data/Containers/Bundle/Application/....../......app/.... Reason: image not found dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/hugofv/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/20E232/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3.17C45 DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/hugofv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArtMe-azduvkqrxsfdfmgyrnagtfphohqs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 13.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framewor`

And when I run by Command Line the app not opening, It's open and close without show error.

Comment: Which framework are you trying to install? Are you using CocoaPods? In short, your library is expecting this framework to be installed in a path which is malformed or doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I'm using cocoapods. but this lib is third-party from react-native.